# Combination Chart (more than 1 measure) - Lightning Experience Dashboard

Tags: reporting, lightning, dashboard

I would like to compare aggregates from different fields.

Normalized Total Cost vs UnNormalized Total Cost.  In classic I can add another column to compare the 2.  However, in a Lightning Dashboard I cannot figure it out.

The graph would look like this

```
           Normalized   |-------------
Company 1
           UnNormalized |-----------------------

           Normalized   |-------------------
Company 2
           UnNormalized |-------------------
```

Currently I have to display 2 graphs to show the difference.  In classic I could add fields

Company is group by; normalized and unnormalized and summary fields.